# Is there a different way to replace these brackets using Ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string which contains a 2-D array.

```
b= "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]"

c = b.gsub(/(\[\[)/,"[").gsub(/(\]\])/,"]")
```

The above is how I decide to flatten it to:

```
   "[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]"
```

Is there a way to replace the leftmost and rightmost brackets without doing a double `gsub` call?  I'm doing a deeper dive into regular expressions and would like to see different alternatives.

Sometimes, the string may be in the correct format as comma delimited 1-D arrays.

Comment: Does your input array actually begin `[[1,` rather than `[1,` ?

Comment: Thanks that was a typo...I edited it.

Comment: It could be in the desired format (thanks, I edited above).

Comment: Last question - is it possible that they are ever nested as `[[1,2], [[1,2],[3,4]], [1,2]]`? That is, does the outer dimension only ever occur at the outermost level (the ends of the string)?

Comment: Great question, the outer dimension only occurs at the outermost level.

Comment: This depends a lot on the variety of strings you need to process. Although regexps work in some limited cases, they are not appropriate for parsing general nested structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gsub` method accepts a hash, and anything that matches your regular expression will be replaced using the keys/values in that hash, like so:

```
b = "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]"
c = b.gsub(/\[\[|\]\]/, '[[' => '[', ']]' => ']')
```

That may look a little jumbled, and in practice I'd probably define the list of swaps on a different line. But this does what you were looking for with one gsub, in a more intuitive way.

Another option is to take advantage of the fact that `gsub` also accepts a block:

```
c = b.gsub(/\[\[|\]\]/){|matched_value| matched_value.first}
```

Here we match any double opening/closing square brackets, and just take the first letter of any matches. We can clean up the regex:

```
c = b.gsub(/\[{2}|\]{2}/){|matched_value| matched_value.first}
```

This is a more succinct way to specify that we want to match exactly two opening brackets, or exactly two closing brackets. We can also refine the block:

```
c = b.gsub(/\[{2}|\]{2}/, &:first)
```

Here we're using some Ruby shorthand. If you only need to call a simple method on the object passed into a block, you can use the `&:` notation to do this. I think I've gotten it about as short and sweet as I can. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

```
\[(?=\[)|(?<=\])\]
```

You can try this.Replace with ``.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/25

Answer (score 1):

Don't even bother with a regular expression, just do a simple string slice:

```
b= "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]"
b[1 .. -2] # => "[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]"
```

> the string may be in the correct format as comma delimited 1D arrays

Then sense whether it is and conditionally modify it:

```
b= "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]"
b = b[1 .. -2] if b[0, 2] == '[[' # => "[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]"
```

Regular expressions aren't universal hammers, and not everything is a nail to be hit with one.

Comment: This is a great alternative, but I believe the original poster wanted to learn how to use regex more succinctly. The slice option also prevents him from expanding the solution to more complex strings.

Answer (score 1):

To "squeeze" consecutive occurrences of a specific character set, you can use `tr_s`:

```
"[[1,2],[3,4]]".tr_s('[]','[]')
=> "[1,2],[3,4]"
```

You're saying "translate all runs of square bracket characters to one of that character". To do the same thing with regular expressions and `gsub`, you can do:

```
"[[1,2],[3,4]]".gsub(/(\[|\])+/,'\1')
```